# Losing state of WebForm User Control

Tags: asp.net, webforms

First of all, I have no experiences with ASP.NET WebForms. However, I inherited a very old WebForm application where I have to do maintenance from time to time.  This is such a situation:

There is a user control that has private instance variables.  The problem is, that the values of these instance variables get lost, most likely after page reload.  What I found out so far is, that it seems that the control class gets recreated frequently.  What would be helpful, would be answers to the following questions:

- Do WebForm User Controls do maintain a state?
- If yes, how is it done in general (pointers to online resources for details appreciated)
- If no, can it be implemented somehow? Any samples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the most common way to maintain state is to use ViewState rather than private instance fields.  For example, if your UserControl contains a property `Text`, you can define it as follows:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return (string) ViewState["Text"]; }
    set { ViewState["Text"] = value; }
}
```

You can also delegate a property to a child control.  In this case the child control will maintain ViewState for you (provided `EnableViewState` is `true`).  For example:

```
public string Text
{
    get { return MyTextBox.Text; }
    set { MyTextBox.Text = value; }
}
```

Google for `ViewState` for more info.  There are pitfalls and it's a good idea to understand it thoroughly.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the fast answer.  So my suspicion was right, that UserControls do not maintain state.  Would it be a good alternative to store my transient data in the users session object?

Comment: "Would it be a good alternative to store my transient data in the users session object" - the only answer is "it depends". There are trade-offs for all the options for maintaining state (e.g. querystring values, cookies, ViewState, Session, ASP.NET Cache, server-side database).  This article is a good starting point: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5y3c2c5(v=vs.85).aspx